# How can I chagne the size of the arrow graphics in the scroll bar?

Tags: javafx

Is there any way to change the size of the arrow graphic in the scroll-bar buttons using CSS?

I want the arrows to take up a larger portion of the button. If I set `-fx-scale-shape: false` I can achieve the desired effect by manually scaling the values in `-fx-shape`.

```
.scroll-bar:vertical > .decrement-button > .decrement-arrow {
    -fx-shape: "M0,0 ........... z";
    -fx-position-shape: true;
    -fx-scale-shape: false;
}
```

However, I feel like a better idea would be to keep `-fx-scale-shape: true` but change the container size instead, I just can't figure out how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the `-fx-pref-width` and `height` properties inside the css and then set `-fx-scale-shape: true`.

```
.scroll-bar:vertical > .decrement-button > .decrement-arrow {
    -fx-pref-width: 7;
    -fx-pref-height: 7;
    -fx-shape: "M0,0 ........... z";
    -fx-position-shape: true;
    -fx-scale-shape: true;
}
```